# Details of a user

Tags: php, pdo

Would you please recommend how I could improve this code? My PHP editor only gave a warning about the variable `$id`.

```
require_once 'includes/config.php';

$id = (isset($_GET['id']) || trim($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;

if (!empty($id) && filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
    $sql->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } else {
      $user->redirectTo('index');
  }

  if ($row === false){
      $error[] = "No user found, sorry!";
  }

  if (isset($error)){
      foreach($error as $error){
          echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'.$error.'</div>';
          $user->redirectTo('index');
      }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Is the code currently working correctly? (assuming the warning is not causing the program to not work)

Comment: Hello, it all works perfectly. The syntax is correct? The code (however little) is clean enough?

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. I hope you get some good answers!

Comment: @Okram922: turn on `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL|E_STRICT`, because your ternary that assigns `$id` will emit a notice (undefined index `id`) if `$_GET['id']` wasn't set because of the logical or (should be `&&`)

Comment: I suggest `redirectTo()` method must be in another place rather than `user` object. It's logically not corellated.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $id = (isset($_GET['id']) || trim($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
> ```

Shouldn't the `||` be an `&&`?  The current behavior is that it checks if it is set and if not, it trims off the whitespace.  But there wouldn't be any whitespace if `$_GET['id']` wasn't set.

```
$id = (isset($_GET['id']) && trim($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
```

This version checks if it is set and if so, it trims off whitespace.  If the result of the trim is a string that evaluates as true (not an empty string), it attempts to take the `intval`.  That makes more sense.

You don't say what the warning is, but if the problem is that `$_GET['id']` is not set when you use it, changing the operator should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would always make sure all variables are initialized. This saves a lot of "isset" checks. Also, you can avoid possible errors by unexpected "initialization" defaults.

- $row is never defined. It only makes sense after the execution of the query.
- $error could be initialized as an empty array instead of appending an element only (null would be better, read below)
- $id is already initialized as an integer (using intval or 0)

Also, error is never used as an array. So it would be better to really use it that way, or just change the code to check for NULL.

When `$_GET['id']` is not set, it will trim the `$_GET['id']` value but actually do nothing with it. You can entirely strip this piece of code.

Another minor suggestion is to select as little as possible to keep the resultset little. instead of `SELECT * FROM users` you could `SELECT id FROM users` instead.

```
require_once 'includes/config.php';

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;

$error = null;
if ($id > 0) {
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = :id");
    $sql->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($row === false){
        $error = "No user found, sorry!";
    }
} else {
    $user->redirectTo('index');
}


if ($error !== null){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'.$error.'</div>';
    $user->redirectTo('index');
}
```

If you don't like the $error !== null, you can always remove the !== null, since null is falsey.